# Can I specify the redirect address after logging in on the initial request in Spring Boot OAuth2 client?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm developing a web app cross-platform app, and the redirect addresses required during social login differ between the web and app environments. I want to set the final redirect_uri in the social login request, like

`http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=foo://` and `http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=bar://`.

Is there a way to solve this?

I wanted to intercept the first request in the OAuth2 filter and pass the redirect_uri to the final successHandler, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Show your client registration.

Answer (score 0):

Different redirect addresses are returned according to different login clients, like the following?

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http,ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository ) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2Login(c -> c.authorizationEndpoint(cc->cc.authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository))))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .build();
    }

    static class CustomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver{
        private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver;

        public CustomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
            DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver =
                    new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI);
            resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(builder -> {
                if (isWebLogin()) {
                    builder.redirectUri("foo://");
                }else if (isAppLogin()) {
                    builder.redirectUri("bar://");
                }
            });
            this.resolver = resolver;
        }

         
        @Override
        public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return resolver.resolve(request);
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
            return resolver.resolve(request,clientRegistrationId);
        }
    }
```